# It'd be like a dream come true!

Tags: phrase-request

I want to write a sentence that conveys the following meaning:

> If I am able to *do XYZ*, it would be like a *dream come true for me*!

examples of *do XYZ* are: "have dinner with your favorite athlete", "click a selfie with the rockstar", "study physics together with your maths professor", etc. To generalize, it could be **any action that** **one has been hoping to do for a long**. Through this sentence, they're expressing their wish as to how their *dreams would come true* if they were finally able to perform their desired action.

I wish to know what different idioms/phrases/words there are that will help me convey this desire in written English. I wish to use these different idioms/phrases/words to bring greater variety to my essay.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I could do XYZ, I would be:

- [*in seventh heaven*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/seventh-heaven)
- [*on cloud nine*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/on-cloud-nine)
- [*tickled pink*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/to-be-tickled-pink)

These expressions all mean "elated" or "very happy."

I listed these because you asked for phrases or idioms – in both your question and in your tag.

That said, you also mention a written essay, and such clichés often don't work well in formal writing. I'd recommend using a word such as *elated* or *ecstatic* instead:

> *If I could do XYZ, I would be **[thrilled](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/thrilled)**.*

Comment: Oh, I didn't know phrases and idioms are not to be used in formal english 
:-O. Elated and ecstatic work just as well, and those phrases are also close to what I wished to use. Thanks!

Comment: @GaurangTandon - You don't necessarily need to avoid phrases and idioms, but _clichés_.

Comment: "cliche - a phrase or opinion that is overused and betrays a lack of original thought" Sorry but I don't read much English literature. How would I know if a particular phrase is cliched? Is there a general rule for that?

Answer (score 1):

Not to encourage you to use overused expressions, but here are several...

landmark

milestone

watershed

breakthrough

turning point

Comment: That's a different interpretation of the question, these words seem to convey the meaning "when a company achieves targeted sales, how to describe it? It could be a landmark, milestone, etc..". I believe JR's answer below more accurately captured what I wished to say. Still, your list is also useful to have, so thanks!

Comment: @Guarang Tandon: You could use all of these phrases to describe a significant personal experience as well.